# Vertical spacing using kern in a custom symbol

Tags: macros, kerning

I've created a new symbol using the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\qc}{$\square$\kern-0.58em{s}}
\begin{document}
\qc
\end{document}
```

However I'd like the letter 's' to be centered vertically, how can I do this?

Comment: How is this symbol going to be used? In text mode, or in math mode? Should the lower line of the square be placed on the baseline (and hence should `s` be above the baseline), or should the square be pushed down a bit so that the `s` is on the baseline?

Comment: @Mico, the use is as a custom replacement of the QED symbol. I'd like the 's' to raised a bit so it does not intersect the lower line of the square. Moving either component is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the baseline of the open square is supposed to be on the typographic basedline, the following code may be of interest. (By using `\ooalign`, one doesn't have to insert a kern after the "s" glyph.) The `d` and `b` characters are there just to indicate the overall size of the composite symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\square" macro
\newcommand{\qc}{%
  \ooalign{$\square$\cr\kern0.21em\raise0.28ex\hbox{s}}}
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\footnotesize d\qc b
\small      d\qc b
\normalsize d\qc b
\large      d\qc b
\Large      d\qc b
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just saw your comment. To use the new composite symbol as a replacement QED-symbol, load (say) the `amsmath` package and issue the instruction `\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\qc}`.

Comment: I'm using it with `\begin{proof}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\qc}`

Comment: @AthenaWidget -- That'll certainly work as well; it'll keep the redefinition of the QED symbol "local" to the given `proof` environment.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want a math symbol. If not, it would be easy to adjust the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\qc{%
  \mathrel{% <-- or \mathbin, or ...
    \vphantom{\square}%
    \mathpalette\aw@qc\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\aw@qc}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$#1\square$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$#1\mathrm{s}$}%
  \dimen@=.5\dimexpr\ht\z@-\ht\tw@\relax
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\square$\cr
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box\tw@\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\footnotesize $d\qc b$

\small      $d\qc b$

\normalsize $d\qc b_{\qc}$

\large      $d\qc b$

\Large      $d\qc b$

\end{document}
```

For each math style, the amount of raising is computed as half the height of the square minus the height of ‘s’. With `\ooalign` we get the superposition.

[image]

If you want a substitute for the QED marker in `amsthm`, here's the code. The `twocolumn` option is just for making a smaller picture.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qc}{%
  \begingroup
  \vphantom{\openbox}%
  \sbox\z@{\openbox}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\mathrm{s}$}%
  \dimen@=.5\dimexpr\ht\z@-\ht\tw@\relax
  \ooalign{%
    \box\z@\cr
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box\tw@\hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\qc}
Some proof with the modified symbol at the end of the line.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Some proof with the standard symbol at the end of the line.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]